# How to write to a csv file in a while Loop python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, datetime

I believe I have everything set up properly. However, my csv file is always blanks.

```
import csv
import datetime, time
with open("hello.csv",'w') as file1:
    wr=csv.writer(file1)
    while True:
        myDate = datetime.datetime.now()
        wr.writerow([myDate])
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: This will never end

Comment: works fine for me, are you sure you ran the program, and closed it before checking the csv file? if it is still lank can you comment the python version you are using?

Comment: @AmitBerger did you have to stop in manually? This will run infinitely.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I ran it for a few seconds and after that just existed the program (Ctrl + C). I assume he will add the exit in the future and just wanted to check the csv writer

Comment: _However, my csv file is always blanks._ The OP does not. The execution is being stopped, so the file is left open with no content.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I am using Visual studio code with code runner and just exiting the program

Comment: That won't work. Your code needs to exit properly to save the file.

Answer (score 0):

You loop never ends and you'll never be able to see the changes done to the file.

If you want your CSV file to be updated in real-time, a workaround for your problem would be to print the time every five seconds like you do and then redirect the standard output to a file.

Your could would look like:

```
import sys
import datetime, time
while True:
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    time.sleep(5)
```

Running it in a GNU/Linux terminal

```
$ nohup python my_program.py > output.csv &
$ tail -f output.csv
```

You should be able to see the file being written in real time.